# Вычисление неявных уравнений

Tags: c#, математика, геометрия

У меня есть вот это уравнение, где `x` - искомая переменная, а все остальные - подставляемые константы.
[image: Формула]

Мне нужно получить x, но ее выражение из уравнения было всегда безуспешным. Пытался на многих сайтах его занести, тоже не получалось. Вот оно `m+(x-n)*(b/2*n+c*m+e/2)/(a*x+b/2*m+d/2) = (-(b*x+e)+sqrt((b*x+e)^2-4*c*(a*x*x+d*x-1)))/(2*c)`. Мне вообще кажется, что это уравнение нельзя привести к явному виду. Возможно ли в C# рассчитать такое? Типо подставить в константы значения и потом все посокращать и вывести `x`. Если да, то как?

Comment: C# - это язык программирования, а не математическое ПО, он вам просто так из коробки ничем не поможет.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, его и аналитически решить можно - подставить константы, получится что-то вида ax+b=(cx+d)(ex+f+sqrt(gx^2+hx+i)), раскрыть, etc etc... Но проще - численно, вам же не аналитический вид нужен?...

Comment: @tym32167 Я же не знал. Может быть какие-то либы есть

Comment: @Harry Мне нужно просто вычислить переменную x, только значение, а константы могут быть разные численно

Comment: Ну так решайте численно, в чем проблема? (Кроме той, что в общем виде может решения и не быть). Все равно в аналитическом виде зашьетесь - вот его решение: https://fex.net/ru/s/vf2amyb

Comment: Кстати, интересно бы посмотреть *начальную* задачу, потому что ощущение нехорошее, что решается все на самом деле несколько проще...

Comment: @Harry Возможно, скорее всего проще. Задача такая - есть общее уравнение эллипса, и надо найти координаты его центра. Я подумал можно было бы найти нормаль в любой точке, вычислить точки пересечения, и центр отрезка был бы центром эллипса. В итоге эта идея вылелась в вот это уравнение

Comment: **ТЮЮЮЮЮ!!!!!!**  Это ж ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи... В каком виде дано общее уравнение? Нет, в чат не зовите, давайте исходное уравнение в вопрос. И - гарантия, чтьо это эллипс, есть? Ну, там, соответствующие дискриминанты с тем знаком, что надо?

Comment: A, B, C, D, E известны
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey = 1. Гарантия эллипса есть. Он никогда не расходится

Comment: Ага, вот и XY проблема, скорее всего центр эллипса находится гораздо проще.

Comment: Да, вдогонку - нормаль к любой точке совершенно не обязательно проходит через центр; это справедливо только для окружности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного математики. На ночь глядя все выкладки проводить и приводить тяжко, так что просто приведу картинками.

Итак, сначала находите все *a*<sub>ij</sub>:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего найти инварианты - раз плюнуть, а заодно и центр - вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все! Думаю, справитесь?

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Спасибо большое